# I would like an iPad app for annotating my games

Tags: learning, software, annotation

I would like an app for annotating my games and/or replay others' games.  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stockfish](http://stockfishchess.org/) works well for this purpose; and it's free software.

Comment: This is not true. Stockfish does not allow games to be annotated.

Answer (score 1):

Giordano Vicoli's Chess Studio Light allows you to add variations, text comments and some NAGs (!, ?) to the game notation window. Stockfish deletes the main line when you enter an alternate move.

Comment: SmallChess allows the main line be retained. See my answer.

Comment: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9234/scid-or-any-alternative-on-ipad/12426?noredirect=1#comment16008_12426

Answer (score 1):

My app, SmallChess allows the most advanced chess analytic.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't find this on the App Store. Is it only available in certain countries?

Comment: @BU982T it's available to all. Search for iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

[Chess-wise](https://appsto.re/gb/R1paV.i) is the only iOS app that I'm aware of that has an annotation function and an import function.